# Formula to Calculate: Start Date + Duration (Days) = End Date ; Business Days M-F

Tags: calculated-column

Basically, I'm trying to use SharePoint as some what of a project tool for tasks.

On a new task, we have **"START DATE"**, and a custom number field **"ETC"**. I'd like to have a calculated field **"END DATE"** populated by adding the **ETC** (estimated time to complete) to the **START DATE**, but the result should display a date that is within a business work week (Monday through Friday).

i.e.

```
Start Date = 4/8/2015

ETC = 8 Days

End Date (excluding weekends) = 4/20/2015  (Calculated Field)
```

Comment: check thi http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/working-days-weekdays-holidays-sharepoint-calculated-columns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=[START DATE]+[ETC] 
+ ROUNDDOWN([ETC]/5,0)*2 
+ IF(WEEKDAY([START DATE])+MOD([ETC],5)>=7,2,0)
- ROUNDDOWN(WEEKDAY([START DATE])/7,0) 
+ IF(AND(MOD([ETC],5)=0,WEEKDAY([START DATE])=1),-2,0)  
+ IF(AND(MOD([ETC],5)=0,WEEKDAY([START DATE])=7),-2,0)
```

[Here's where I copied this from.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306475/sharepoint-column-default-values-add-10-working-days)

Comment: Perfect, wow, I was starting to think I couldn't do this. Thank you!

Comment: Does this work in infopath?